# How to get Dynamic table row values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table whose rows are created when page loaded,at the end of the row there is a cross button so what I am trying to do is,when I click that button I want to have the values inside the current row, I have `ItemName`,`I Code`,`Price` any many more so I want some fields value when I click that button, My all the cells are in form of input fields only

**What I am doing**

```js
function rowappend(tbody) {

  const markup =
    `<tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
    </td>
             
    <td>
      <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" value="0.00">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="unittd" id="unittd" class="form-control commantd">
    <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn" ></i></td>
    
  </tr>`

  $(tbody).append(markup);

}
rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'));
$(document).on("click", ".remove-btn", function(e) {
  $.confirm({
    title: '',
    content: 'Do you want to clear ?',
    buttons: {
      Yes: () => {
        keys: ['enter', 'space']
        action: function() {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var td = tr.find("td").eq(4);
          var input = td.find('input');
          alert(input.val())
          tr.remove();
        },
      },
      No: function() {

      },

    }
  })
}) $(document).keypress(function(event) {
  const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement

  var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keycode == '13') {
    if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {

      if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
        rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<div class="row tableGrn" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
        <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">I Code</th>
        <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">MRP</th>
        <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Price</th>
        <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
        <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc %</th>
        <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
        <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">GST %</th>
        <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">GST Amt</th>
        <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amt</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` in your click function refer to the `<i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn" ></i>` so `$(this).find('td')` will return nothing. You need to use `$(this).closest('tr')` to get the row first.

```js
function rowappend(tbody) {

  const markup =
    `<tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
    </td>
             
    <td>
      <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" value="0.00">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="unittd" id="unittd" class="form-control commantd">
    <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn" ></i></td>
    
  </tr>`

  $(tbody).append(markup);

}
rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'));
$(document).on("click", ".remove-btn", function(e) {
  $.confirm({
    title: '',
    content: 'Do you want to clear ?',
    buttons: {
      Yes: {
        keys: ['enter', 'space'],  
        action: () => {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var td = tr.find("td").eq(4);
        var input = td.find('input');
        alert(input.val())
        tr.remove();
        }
      },
      No: function() {

      },

    }
  })
})
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement

  var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keycode == '13') {
    if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {

      if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
        rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div class="row tableGrn" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
        <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">I Code</th>
        <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">MRP</th>
        <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Price</th>
        <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
        <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc %</th>
        <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
        <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">GST %</th>
        <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">GST Amt</th>
        <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amt</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: hey can you help me out I have a small doubt regarding this question

Comment: Yes. What's your problem?

Comment: hey I have edited my post what  I am doing is when I click on cross button I am trying to as user if he/she wants to delete or not for that I am using `jquery confer.min.js` but after using along this the values are showing up undefined

Comment: i editted my answer to solve your problem. When you use `Yes: function() {`, the `this` inside this funtion is not the button anymore. You should use arrow function instead `Yes: () => {`

Comment: hey sorry to bother you again If you have some time then please check my edit what I am trying to do is `dispose` and  `execute` yes no with key board button that's why using `action` inside yes but it is not working  `Yes: () => {  keys: ['enter','space']action: function () {`

Comment: check the answer again, look like you have syntax error somewhere. Note that if using `this` then be careful when use `function()` inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onclick event for the '.remove-btn'.

```
   /* Adding onclick event  */
<i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn" onclick="fnRemoveRow(this);"></i>

 /*Javascript code */
 function fnRemoveRow(_this)
 {
     var $tr=$(_this).closest('tr');
     var itemName = $tr.find("#itemNametd").val();  
     /* Get other values */
      $tr.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find out the parent of that cross button and then find out the value.

Make sure do not use Ids if you are creating multiple rows and do not access using the id because it should be unique and I assumed there will be more then row in this list

```
$('.remove-btn').click(function(e) {
/* First find out parent of X button then inside that find input element and then value.
I have added here the name while finding the perticular value you can use the id as well but it will not work  if more then 1 row.
*/
alert($(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="itemNametd"]').val())
$(this).closest('tr').remove();})}
```